# C#: SA1401 stylecop warning unable to be removed

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, stylecop

I have trying to suppress the SA1401(Field names should be private) warning using the following code:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.NamingRules", "SA1306:FieldNamesMustBeginWithLowerCaseLetter", Justification = "Some field names should be capital letters")]
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.StyleCop.CSharp.Maintainability", "SA1401:FieldsMustBePrivate", Justification = "Some fields must be public")]
[EventSource(Guid = "9E1C02F1-9B14-4906-AA88-ED2140A102B7")]
public class ProcessApiEventSource : EventSource
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Event source logger instance
    /// </summary>
    public static ProcessApiEventSource Log = new ProcessApiEventSource();
    ...
}
```

While SA1306 warning are being suppressed, SA1401 warnings are not being suppressed. Can anyone suggest why the suppress is not working? Also, is there a way to change the declaration using accessors so that the code adheres to that rule and is clear of that warning itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the error to go away, you can convert the public field to a private field, and expose it as a public property.

```
public class ProcessApiEventSource : EventSource
{
    private static ProcessApiEventSource MyLog = new ProcessApiEventSource();

    public static ProcessApiEventSource Log  { get { return MyLog; } }
}
```

And if you are using .NET 4.6, then you can use a getter-only property expression as well.

```
public class ProcessApiEventSource : EventSource
{
    public static ProcessApiEventSource Log => new ProcessApiEventSource();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.MaintainabilityRules", "SA1401:FieldsMustBePrivate", Justification = "Some fields must be public")]
```

I used this to suppress the message as described [here](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1401.md).